# Making File Dialog only accept directories

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, filedialog

I want to have a file dialog only allow directories, here's what I've been trying:

```
fileDialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
fileDialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
filename = fileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select USB Drive Location'))
```

Answer (score 6):

What I wanted is:

```
directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Select USB Drive Location')
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an old question, I know, but perhaps this will help someone else.

Use this snippet inside the method called to display the file box:

```
dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog(self)
dialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.Directory)
dialog.setOption(QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly, True)

if dialog.exec_():
    for d in dialog.selectedFiles():
        print d
```

Answer (score 1):

The Qt 4.6 docs for ShowDirsOnly says:

> "Only show directories in the file
>   dialog. By default both files and
>   directories are shown. (Valid only in
>   the Directory file mode.)"

Maybe it isn't in "Directory" file mode?